# awk capture input quotes as a single field

Tags: awk, field, quotes

So I have this dataset, that the first column starts with the name inside quotes. Is it possible to capture the name as a single field?

```
"Mazda RX4" 21 6 160 110 3.9 2.62 16.46 0 1 4 4
"Mazda RX4 Wag" 21 6 160 110 3.9 2.875 17.02 0 1 4 4
"Datsun 710" 22.8 4 108 93 3.85 2.32 18.61 1 1 4 1
"Hornet 4 Drive" 21.4 6 258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44 1 0 3 1
"Hornet Sportabout" 18.7 8 360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02 0 0 3 2
"Valiant" 18.1 6 225 105 2.76 3.46 20.22 1 0 3 1
"Duster 360" 14.3 8 360 245 3.21 3.57 15.84 0 0 3 4
"Merc 240D" 24.4 4 146.7 62 3.69 3.19 20 1 0 4 2
"Merc 230" 22.8 4 140.8 95 3.92 3.15 22.9 1 0 4 2
"Merc 280" 19.2 6 167.6 123 3.92 3.44 18.3 1 0 4 4
```

Note that sometimes the name is single field (like "Valiant"), sometimes 2 (like "Mazda RX4" or 3 "Mazda RX4 Wag")

So base on the number of fields, I came up with this awk code that works as I wanted, however I wonder if there is any other systematic way to do so?

```
awk '{name=$1; for (i=2; i<=NF-11; i++) name=name " " $i; printf "%s\n", name}' data/mtcars.dat | head
Mazda RX4
Mazda RX4 Wag
Datsun 710
Hornet 4 Drive
Hornet Sportabout
Valiant
Duster 360
Merc 240D
Merc 230
Merc 280
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `"` as the input field separator. That would assign an empty field to $1, the full name to $2, and the rest of the line to $3.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\""}{print $2}' < test.dat
```

```
Mazda RX4
Mazda RX4 Wag
Datsun 710
Hornet 4 Drive
Hornet Sportabout
Valiant
Duster 360
Merc 240D
Merc 230
Merc 280
```

Comment: +1; a POSIX-compliant solution; slightly more concise reformulation: `awk -F\" '{print $2}' test.dat`

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it as short as possible:

```
awk -F\" '$0=$2' file
Mazda RX4
Mazda RX4 Wag
Datsun 710
Hornet 4 Drive
Hornet Sportabout
Valiant
Duster 360
Merc 240D
Merc 230
Merc 280
```

Or some more robust:

```
awk -F\" '{$0=$2}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk NF=1 FPAT='[^"]+'
```

Result

```
Mazda RX4
Mazda RX4 Wag
Datsun 710
Hornet 4 Drive
Hornet Sportabout
Valiant
Duster 360
Merc 240D
Merc 230
Merc 280
```

Comment: Is splitting by content (FPAT) only in GNU awk?

Comment: No, that's my direct, straightforward way of asking whether it's only in GNU awk. It's not supported by mawk, which is the version that ships with Ubuntu. It's a great feature; one more reason to switch to GNU awk.

Comment: Enticingly concise, but obscure: `NF=1` is the actual awk _program_, whereas `FPAT='[^"]+'` is a pseudo filename that defines the `FPAT` variable (equivalent: `awk -v FPAT='[^"]+' 'NF=1' test.dat`). _Pattern_ `NF=1` is effectively the equivalent of _action_ `{print $1}`: it tells `awk` to limit the number of fields to 1, causing `$0` to be replaced with the value of `$1`; since the pattern `NF=1` (which happens to be an assignment here) results in 1 (read: true) and there's no associated action, the default is to _print_ the (modified) input line, effectively printing `$1` in this case.

Comment: It is not use of a `gawk`-specific feature, but the _construction_ of your solution that makes it obscure (but concise). In fact, there's even a shorter POSIX-compliant solution using the same logic: `awk '$0=$2' FS=\"` (17 chars.) or, even shorter, with `-F`: `awk -F\" '$0=$2'` (16 chars.). I struggled to understand your solution at first, so I thought my explaining it may help others.

Comment: I gave you -1 since you did not write the limitation on `FPAT` in your post. As far as I know, this is not only `gnu awk` but need at least version `4.x`